# SwingWorkers stopped working

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm having a very strange problem. I was working on an application using Swing, and of course I'm using SwingWorkers. They were working porperly until last night. I just ran the programm, but the workers stopped working from one run to the next. (I actually didn't change a single line of code).
Was there some update or something else going on last night that could explain this strange behaviour?

I'm using JavaSE-1.6 on an OpenSuSE 11.1 box. I'm developing with Eclipse Galileo.

Comment: did you add anything to EventQueue.invokeLater?

Comment: No, actually I didn't change anything.

Comment: can you paste your code here? a section of code where there might be problem.

Comment: I would've done that, but I'm dealing with about 15 different SwingWorkers which all stopped working from one moment to the other. I didn't implement any 'special' behaviour and until last night, they worked without a problem.

Comment: cool! but please update the status in the question. dont write as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two things I have learnt about SwingWorkers is

1. Java will run only one swing worker at a time (they get queued)
2. Once swing workers complete execution, you cannot use them again. You will have to create a new instance of the swing worker if you want to run them again.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the problem on my own, here the solution if you're interested:

A change in the database I wasn't aware of increased the number of (dynamically created) SwingWorkers above 10, which is the maximum number of possible workers.